# SplashScreen not showing react native eas

Tags: react-native, expo, eas

I've builded my app with `eas build -p android --profile preview` and when i download and run my app `splash.png` image not showing it shows just empty white screen here my `app.json`:

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "{app name}",
    "slug": "{app-slug}",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "userInterfaceStyle": "light",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true
    },
    "android": {
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/adaptive-icon.png"
      },
      "package": "{package name}"
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png"
    },
    "extra": {
      "eas": {
        "projectId": "{project id}"
      }
    },
    "build": {
      "preview": {
        "android": {
          "buildType": "apk"
        }
      },
      "preview2": {
        "android": {
          "gradleCommand": ":app:assembleRelease"
        }
      },
      "preview3": {
        "developmentClient": true
      },
      "production": {}
    }
  }
}
```

There is no errors while building my app.  And here `eas.json`:

```
{
  "cli": {
    "version": ">= 3.16.0"
  },
  "build": {
    "development": {
      "developmentClient": true,
      "distribution": "internal"
    },
    "preview": {
      "distribution": "internal"
    },
    "production": {}
  },
  "submit": {
    "production": {}
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

set the resizeMode to cover, and change the background color of the splash or double check if your splash screen contains white colors because it will not be shown, if the backg is white.

Comment: I have tried it but it doesn't work.

Comment: Are you sure that you have added the correct name for the image?

Comment: Yeah, i'm 100% sure the correct name/path for the image cause when i run the application by locally like with android studio splash screen image shows